# Is it possible to combine API's of stripe/paypal with bitcoin processing API?

Tags: api, stripe-payments, bitcoin

I am very new to bitcoin, payment processing and API's.I would like to understand more about it. Is it possible to combine API's of stripe/paypal with bitcoin processing API. If it is possible, what is the procedure to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kkuryllo mentioned, what do you mean by "combine"?

For a hackathon, I used coinbases API with stripes API. Basically, people entered their bitcoin address, and an amount of BTC they want to buy. Then it redirected them to stripes api and once the cc transaction was confirmed, I sent the amount of BTC they purchased.

Comment: Yes I was referring to something similar, only that I was wondering if bitpay could be integrated with stripe. Are there any tutorials/blogs which will explain on how coinbases API can be integrated with Stripe?Also is it possible to test this with dummy data/ dummy bitcoins without actually having to buy bitcoin?

Comment: I actually used  the API docs for both as well as Stack Overflow for reference. You can easily switch out BitPay for Coinbase, but if I were you, I would stick to coinbase.

If you email Coinbase's support, they will give you $5 worth of bitcoins for free to test.